# Add Post Status to Body Class

Tags: css, post-status

I have added a custom post status of rejected, working just fine.

I want to add the post status to the body of the post when it is being previewed. In order to style a front end information box seen by the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the `body_class` hook in the `functions.php` file of your theme in combination with `get_post_status()` function. Like the following:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( get_post_status() == 'rejected' ) {
        $classes[] = 'rejected';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Scott that totally does the trick!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Now please mark it as accepted answer, so that other people may find it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late to the party, but for those who might be interested, this can be accomplished without custom code. There is a plugin in the WordPress repository called [WP247 Body Classes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp247-body-classes/). You can use the **Custom Classes** section to add your own custom body classes. In this case, simply adding the following line of code will give you a body class called `is-poststat-?` where `?` will be the post status.

```
$classes[] = 'is-poststat-' . get_post_status();
```

Then you can tailor your pages using CSS and checking for `body.is-poststat-publish` or `body.is-poststat-rejected`.

Hope this helps someone.